# Very strange chrome bug with z-index and position:fixed

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've to do a very quick frontend build on a temp site,

There's an odd bug that only appears occasionally in Chrome, and it's the sticky header that is sometimes positioned underneath the content.  It has a z-index of 10, none of the content that has positioning is has a higher z-index than this.

The strangest thing is that it only appears occasionally and not everytime, like 5-10% of the time, which makes testing very difficult.

I tried removing the 3d transform on the nav element but the bug still persists.  It seems it is some kind of rendering issue but It's critical I find out the cause because we cannot launch with a bug like this for obvious reasons.

link: 
http://wasabiadmin.se/getillbaka/

I can't really post any code because I am not sure what could be causing it.  I don't think it would be helpful to post reams of code in this instance.
The elemement with the bug has the class of .navbar located as a descendent of .site-header for quick viewing in Chrome Dev tools.

If anybody can shed any light on this really unusual behaviour I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issue:

As your header is using  `position: relative; z-index: 10;`, give your container the following style:

```
.page-content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
}
```

This will make sure your header is always over your container.

Comment: This should, in theory work.  Surprised I didn't think of that.  I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: Implemented the suggested fix now and it's live on the link in my original post.  After like the 30th page refresh the header was once again behind the content.  Very very strange.

Comment: Note:  When I change ANYTHING else on the page in the dev tools, like padding-bottom in the footer, that causes the page to re-paint the bug goes away.

Comment: When normally does this happen? On scrolling? I have refreshed several times and still I can't find the issue, I'm using the latest dev version of Chrome.

Comment: It's when the page loads, more often than not on a hard refresh, but like I said it's very inconsistent like 5% or less of the time it occurs.  But it's enough that the client has noticed and wants it fixing.

Comment: I see. You should try different ways, remove the `z-index` and `position: relative;`from `.navbar-wrap` and add that to `header`. 
Are you using a plug-in for the header?

Comment: I have written my own js to control the header, no plugins there.  I will try what you suggested thanks.

Comment: Have you noticed it again? It might be because of opacity bug as well.

Comment: None of that seemed to work, could you elaborate on opacity bug? because it does have an opacity fade-in as the site loads.

Comment: opacity and z-index sometimes get buggy in Chrome and Safari, but I need to encounter the issue in action to see what exactly is causing it. However it would be best and time saving to rewrite the code with a different method for your nav bar, that shouldn't be too difficult, and most probably it's not going to happen with the new code.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I found the culprit.  In short I was applying an opacity transition to fade in the navbar.  Apparently Chrome doesn't like opacity to be transitioned on a position:fixed element, or any element that has a descendant that has position:fixed set.

Comment: Glad you found the culprit!

Comment: Done.  Thanks again,  Can't upvote because  I don't have a reputation but when I do I'll come back and throw in an upvote :)

Comment: Although I must add The code in the original answer isn't the fix, it's removing opacity from any parent/ancestor of the position fixed element - maybe the answer should be ammended to reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the z-index on the parent (header in your case) and add a position:relative

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I already tried this before, but to no avail.  I should have mentioned this in my question.  I think Nima's suggestion will do the trick.